# How is the unattended-upgrades notification email built?

Tags: email, exim, unattended-upgrades

I defined unattended-upgrade configuration in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades file. It works fine, I receive an email notification when an upgrade is applied.

The notificatoin email shows this subject: `unattended-upgrades result for debian.example.com: SUCCESS`.

Where does that debian.example.com comes from? I could not find it in the configuration file.
How could I add my VPS name instead? (I am using Exim4, and /etc/email-addresses is empty, is this related?)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The email subject is constructed [as follows](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/0d2527c6f24f49e620bc0ea6107764412e2fb7c7/unattended-upgrade#L1467):

```
    subject = _(
        "{hold_flag}{reboot_flag} unattended-upgrades result for "
        "{machine}: {result}").format(
            hold_flag=hold_flag_str, reboot_flag=reboot_flag_str,
            machine=host(), result="SUCCESS" if res else "FAILURE").strip()
```

The machine name is the result of `host()`, which is [defined as](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/0d2527c6f24f49e620bc0ea6107764412e2fb7c7/unattended-upgrade#L1349)

```
def host():
    # type: () -> str
    return socket.getfqdn()
```

So `debian.example.com` is your FQDN, which you can see by running

```
hostname --fqdn
```

This is usually stored in `/etc/hostname`; changes to that should show up in the `unattended-upgrade` emails.